# How to extract an association with similar keys from another association?

Tags: associations, filtering

Considering we have an association like:

```
asc1 =  <|"a.s.r"->1, "a.s.r345" -> 45, "asc" -> "cas", "qwrs" -> 78, "a.s.r[4]/vu" -> 4, "es" -> 74|>
```

How to extract an `asc2` to include only the pairs where key starts with `"a.s.r"`, as the following:

```
asc2 = <|"a.s.r"->1, "a.s.r345" -> 45, "a.s.r[4]/vu" -> 4|>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cleanest may be [`KeySelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeySelect.html) and [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html):

```
asc1 // KeySelect[StringMatchQ[#, "a.s.r*"] &]
```

> ```
> <|"a.s.r" -> 1, "a.s.r345" -> 45, "a.s.r[4]/vu" -> 4|>
> ```

---

Responding to the follow-up questions in the comments:

```
Count[Keys @ asc1, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "a.s.r*"]]
```

> 3

```
asc1 // KeySelect[! StringMatchQ[#, "a.s.r*"] &]
```

> ```
> <|"asc" -> "cas", "qwrs" -> 78, "es" -> 74|>
> ```

Also:

```
GroupBy[Normal@asc1, StringMatchQ[First@#, "a.s.r*"] &, Association]
```

> ```
> <|True -> <|"a.s.r" -> 1, "a.s.r345" -> 45, "a.s.r[4]/vu" -> 4|>, 
>  False -> <|"asc" -> "cas", "qwrs" -> 78, "es" -> 74|>|>
> ```

Or to modify `asc1` in-place:

```
asc1 ~KeyDropFrom~ Keys[asc2];

asc1
```

> ```
> <|"asc" -> "cas", "qwrs" -> 78, "es" -> 74|>
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to check if I have more than 1 "a.s.r*" or any other key in my association?

Comment: And also how can I extract asc1 from asc, so that to have asc2 without asc1

Comment: @SuTron See update.